# Fetching column data with same name from multiple tables without using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables with the same column name but they are not related by any primary, foreign key. They are two different columns. While using join i want the result to display both the columns with their actual names. I am getting error The column 'xx' was specified multiple times for 'yy'. I know this can be resolved by using alias names but is there any other solution where we can get the results with the actual names?

Comment: Why would you wish to accomplish something like this?

Comment: this is my brother darrell, and this is my other brother darell.

I.e. No.

Comment: @astander - i need this becos in my code (C#) the results maps to corresponding classes. If the names wont match i have trouble in mapping the result to their types

Comment: Surely if you return the same name for different columns you **wont** be able to map because your code wont know which field to pick?

Comment: Ya thanx. Sorry for being dumb at my last point. I figured it out. I modified the code to handle this appropriately. Just curious to know if showing the actual column names (same name) from multiple tables is possible or not. Thanks for everyone's comment

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
SELECT x.foo, y.foo FROM x, y
```